# ASP.NET Core and Azure Functions

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions

How could i organize my code in Visual Studio if I wanted to develop an ASP.NET Core application wherein the web services would be REST HTTPs which I plan to host in Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Visual Studio 2017 or later extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version) that can be used that allows you to create Function applications as a new project rather easily. There is more documentation for how to structures those projects [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs).

In terms of developing an API, you should use various Http Triggers. These allow you to specify a route and methods that each Azure Function supports. The main difference in comparison to the MVC pattern is that there are no controllers.

Microsoft provides general guidance for API design using Azure Functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api).

Comment: Thanks. But none of the links explain how to create a client application(asp.net) that will consume the functions. And can be consumed locally for development and remotely when deployed

Comment: EDIT: So what I would like is to have a standard ASP.NET project. This is where I will host web pages which will connect to a backend web service. The web service is actually a series of Azure Functions of HTTP trigger. The problem I am having is how could set this up in Visual Studio. Such that during development I can interface the Azure functions locally but when deployed the endpoint are all appended accurately. Like how it happens in traditional web apps?